# Single Responsibility Principle

Tags: oop, single-responsibility-principle

This is a question from past paper.

[image: SRP]

In the question above, I think there are three responsibilities, One for updating employee record, one for calculation of salaray and taxes, and one for getting hour reports.
I would reorganise the above interface as:

```
public interface IChangeEmployee{
 void UpdateEmployee(Employee employee);
 void CreateEmployee(Employee employee);
}
public interface ICalculation{
 void CalculateSalary();
 double CalculateTax();
}
public interface IReports{
void SendHourReports();
}
```

Is my answer a valid one or please correct me?
Thanks

Comment: Since its from a past paper; what was your answer and what were the results?

Comment: The OP posted the attempted answer. I guess there aren't answers to check against.

Answer (score 1):

There is typically no single solution to problems like this, and principles are there to give you guidlines. The principles should be applied **in the context of other surrounding conditions and reqs**, in order to be applied optimally. It is hard to talk about the correct and incorrect design, and much easier about **good and bad design**.

Your proposed application of SRP looks fully ok, considering only the principle. You classified the methods into separated responsabilities according to some logic, you assigned each group to a single interface. Well done! There are of course some other classification you can also make, not less correctly - IContractor (Update and Create) and IAdministrator (all others) also looks ok.

***If the produced design is good or maybe not so good depends on the potential surrounding conditions (or "forces", how they are often called in the theory of design patterns).***

Let's say that in this case we have a company system, and that in context of employment management and recruiting there are 2 internal positions defined - Contractor and Administrator. In consequence, there are corresponding user roles in the system for each one of them. You can now decide to create a separate interface to each one (easy user roles management), providing only the services he has right to perform! In this case a separation in only 2 interfaces would be better, as simpler and covering the reqs perfectly.